# Find all objects within 3D volume

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Totally new to GIS and could use a hand. I have a database table `tracks` containing ADS-B data stored in a Postgres database. Each record has the following columns:

`id, unix_time, latitude, longitude, altitude`

I know I can select all records within some lat and lon using the [ST_Within](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html) function. However, how do I deal with altitude? Is it enough to first filter using ST_Within, and then only select the points that lie within some defined altitude range? Or, is there another way I should be approaching this (i.e., taking the ellipsoid nature of the Earth into consideration)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the 3d functions available to you:

> ST_3DClosestPoint — Returns the 3-dimensional point on g1 that is
> closest to g2. This is the first point of the 3D shortest line.
>
> ST_3DDistance — For geometry type Returns the 3-dimensional cartesian
> minimum distance (based on spatial ref) between two geometries in
> projected units.
>
> ST_3DDWithin — For 3d (z) geometry type Returns true if two geometries
> 3d distance is within number of units.
>
> ST_3DDFullyWithin — Returns true if all of the 3D geometries are
> within the specified distance of one another.
>
> ST_3DIntersects — Tests if two geometries spatially intersect in 3D - only for points, linestrings, polygons, polyhedral surface (area).
>
> ST_3DLongestLine — Returns the 3-dimensional longest line between two
> geometries
>
> ST_3DMaxDistance — For geometry type Returns the 3-dimensional
> cartesian maximum distance (based on spatial ref) between two
> geometries in projected units.
>
> ST_3DShortestLine — Returns the 3-dimensional shortest line between
> two geometries

It sounds like you are trying to get points within a 3d line or 3d polygon?  If so, you should be able to use st_3dintersects to test which points intersect the 3d surface/line.

You can also play with N-D indexes, which use the coordinate dimension of the geometry instead of the standard 2D index.  You create that using `gist_geometry_ops_nd` like this:

```
CREATE INDEX nyc_streets_gix_nd ON nyc_streets
USING GIST (geom gist_geometry_ops_nd);
```

Once you have the N-D indexes, you can do bounding box queries with the `&&&` operator.

**docs**:

> https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/ST_3DIntersects.html
>
> https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/3d.html
>
> https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/reference.html

Comment: Yes, I want to get all points within a 3D polygon. `st_3dintersects` might be the way to go, thanks. If I wanted to instead get all points within a certain radius of another point, am I correct in assuming that `ST_3DWithin` would be the function needed?

Comment: Yes, but it's `st_3ddwithin` - 2 D's for 3D Within Distance